# Change hyperref's links colors without modifing the .tex file

Tags: hyperref

For editing purposes I need to compile a .tex file changing the hyperref's links colors. E.g. if I have:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx} %% This package is already called in the manuscript preamble
\usepackage{xcolor} %% This package could be already called in the manuscript preamble
\usepackage{hyperref} %% This package is already called in the manuscript preamble
\begin{document}

As in eq. \eqref{eq1}
\begin{equation}
 \label{eq1}
x+y=z
\end{equation}

As in figure \ref{fig1}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption.\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I need to be compiled as it was:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx} %% This package is already called in the manuscript preamble
\usepackage{xcolor} %% This package could be already called in the manuscript preamble
\usepackage{hyperref} %% This package is already called in the manuscript preamble

\makeatletter
\def\p@figure{\color{red}}
\def\p@equation{\color{green}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

As in eq. \eqref{eq1}
\begin{equation}
 \label{eq1}
x+y=z
\end{equation}

As in figure \ref{fig1}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption.\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to pass the strings

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\p@figure{\color{red}}
\def\p@equation{\color{green}}
\makeatother
```

to the LaTeX engine:

```
latex "\AtBeginDocument{\makeatletter\def\p@equation{\color{red}}\def\p@equation{\color{green}}\makeatother} \input{mydocument.tex}"
```

but I suppose that `\AtBeginDocument` is not the right place to do it.

I also tried:

```
latex "\makeatletter\def\p@figure{\color{red}}\def\p@equation{\color{green}}\makeatother \input{mydocument.tex}"
```

but only the equation's link color is changed. It doesn't work for the figure's link color.

[image]

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: hyperref is not related, you are not using the colorlinks option, so it doesn't color anything. You could activate colorlinks, but then hyperref would color both in the same color and not one red and the other green.

Comment: Ok, indeed I need different colors for figures, tables, footnotes etc. but in the manuscripts I edit the colorlinks options is always activated.

Comment: Since you talk about hyperref, and show links inside boxes, I think you should force the colorlinks option and set desired link colors for each type. Put the `\PassOptionsToPackage...` directive, or `\AtBeginDocuemnt{\hypersetup...` on the latex command line, as per the existing answer.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau for what I know links to figures, tables, equations... are all of the same type, so, in this way, I can't set a different color for each of them.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Oh yeah; ref vs cite vs hyperlinks are what's distinguished. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
latex "\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{\def\p@figure{\color{red}}\def\p@equation{\color{green}}}\makeatother \input{mydocument.tex}"
```

That is, in the loose form,

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\p@figure{\color{red}}
  \def\p@equation{\color{green}}
}
\makeatother
\input{mydocument.tex}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for the figure's link.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I fixed a typo in my answer, the first `\p@equation` in compact form should be `\p@figure`. If this still cannot solve your problem, you might need to find if `\p@figure` is redefined in your tex file.

Comment: I didn't spot the typo either. Now it works. Thanks.