# Highlight hyperref's links without modifying the general layout

Tags: highlighting

This question is related to my previous one [Change hyperref's links colors without modifing the .tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/545687/33634).

For editing purposes I need to highlight links to figures, tables, footnotes etc. I tried with:

```
\makeatletter
\def\p@figure{\color{red}}
\def\p@equation{\color{green}}
\makeatother
```

But the result is not fully satisfactory.

I'd like something like:

[image]

(obtained with the PDF reader highlight tool).

A very important thing is that this solution must not change the general layout, e.g. adding extra "typesetting" space around the highlighted object, while adding the box, as in the case of a simple `\colorbox` solution.

Comment: Are you using `cleverref` or writing `figure~\cite{...}`, as if it is the latter perhaps you can just wrap this with the `\hl{}` command from the `soul` package.

Comment: I meant `ref` rather than `cite` in my previous comment.

Comment: @oliversm I tried `\hl{\ref{LABEL}}` and \hl{\protect\ref{LABEL}} but it doesn't work. Also I need a layout similar to `\colorbox`, with some extra margins aroung the highlighted object.